# Is it possible to continue parsing with other rules after an exception is raised in semantics?

Tags: python, tatsu

Is it possible to fallback to other rules after an exception is raised in a semantic action? Like the following (contrived) scenario:

```
var = /[a-zA-Z]+/;
keyword = 'for' | 'in';
a = var:var | keyword:keyword;

def a(ast):
    if (ast.var not in symbolTable):
        raise Exception()
```

and when the exception is raised, parsing continues with the 'keyword' rule. I am aware of the @@keyword feature, but I want to declare keywords at runtime (my parser is for a programming language with user-defined operators).

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this?

Comment: I am writing an interpreter for a math-oriented programming language and am using Tatsu to parse the syntax. One issue I'm facing is that since implicit multiplication is supported, the expression f(3) could be parsed as "function f evaluated at 3" or "f * 3". I want to use my symbol table to perform the disambiguation while parsing, by (for example) throwing an exception in the semantic action to mark a rule as failed even after parsing succeeds, and then have the parser continue to the next rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the semantics code raises `tatsu.exceptions.FailedSemantics`, the exception will be treated exactly as a `ParseException`, so the normal parsing control-flow will be resumed.